# Why does it says my browser not supporting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Visual studio code for programming and I'm testing my codes with live server. But today I'm stuck with an error.

My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=,, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test lesson</title>
    <script src="/JS/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <script>
        $(function(){
          $("div").find("*").css({
            "color":"red",
            "border":"2px solid red",
          });
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body class="ancestors">

        <div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div
          <p class="first">P (child)
            <span>Span (grandchild)</span>
          </p>
            <p class="second">P (child)
                <span>Span (grandchild)</span>
            </p>
        </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

So, when i run this code with live server, my browser says :

> `// <![CDATA[ <-- For SVG support if ('WebSocket' in window) { (function () { function refreshCSS() { var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link")); var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) { var elem = sheets[i]; var parent = elem.parentElement || head; parent.removeChild(elem); var rel = elem.rel; if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") { var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, ''); elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf()); } parent.appendChild(elem); } } var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://'; var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws'; var socket = new WebSocket(address); socket.onmessage = function (msg) { if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload(); else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS(); }; if (sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer')) { console.log('Live reload enabled.'); sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true); } })(); } else { console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.'); } // ]]>`

**Can anyone help me please for fix that error?**

Comment: That's not an error message. It's displaying a script as HTML.

Comment: Check your browser for installed extensions

Comment: @Barmar so? how can i fix that?